# RuntimeException in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I've just installed Laravel 5.3. `php artisan serv` also runs.

But as I hit `http://localhost:8000/` on browser I get a `RuntimeException`.

[image: Error]

Is there any solution to prevent this error?

Answer (score 2):

Create cipher key by this command

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Then run server

```
php artisan serve
```

Comment: Yep did it. Thank you.

Comment: Gave you another up-vote as this answer fixed the problem but wasn't marked answered.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this problem always use composer for creating project.

Ex. composer create-project laravel/laravel your_project_name --prefer-dist

if you create project by composer then need not to run this command.

```
  php artisan key:generate
```